# Why does qrcode not work with [ngerman] babel?

Tags: babel, german, qrcode

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\qrcode[height=5cm,level="M"]{BCD\?001\?1\?SCT\?ABCDATWW\?Creditor\?AT611904300234573201\?EUR100\?\?\?My\ Subject}
\end{document}
```

This works. If I switch to language `ngerman` however, LaTeX returns an error:

```
... loadhyph-de-1996.tex:8: Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. 
... loadhyph-de-1996.tex:8: Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete.
```

What gives?

Comment: german uses `"` as a shorthand so that for example `"o` is the accented letter. You can locally turn off shorthands.

Comment: Thank you. `\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}` works a charm. Care to make it an answer?

Comment: I thought it was a duplicate but I can't see it so OK I'll answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

german babel uses `"` as a shorthand so that for example `"`o is the accented letter. You can locally turn off shorthands or globally turn them off with

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print a QRcode, there is no problem: just don't load `babel`.

If your document has parts where German is needed, the also `"` as a shorthand is needed (to break ligatures at morpheme boundaries, for instance, or for getting appropriate hyphenation of composed words).

I suggest to patch `\qrcode` to disable the shorthand.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\qrcode}{\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\qrcode@in}{\endgroup}{}{}


\begin{document}

\qrcode[height=5cm,level="M"]{BCD\?001\?1\?SCT\?ABCDATWW\?Creditor\?AT611904300234573201\?EUR100\?\?\?My\ Subject}

\bigskip

Auf"|lage, nicht Auflage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a German letter, so of course I would like `babel` to work. That said, I can easily do without the shortcuts and disable them routinely: I input umlauts via the keyboard, don't need the fancy conditional-hyphen-handling and `selnolig` takes care of my ligature-related needs. Thanks for the code, though, I'm sure it comes in handy for some (or me in the future, for that matter.)